# Latest ubuntu studio update 22.04 hosed my network

Tags: wireless

So i updated my ubuntu studio 22.04. now i am unable to log on to starlink...i can use a usblive of the SAME os and get on. So i backed up and reinstalled. everything works until i update it!!!! then starlink wont work. I can use my phones hotspot but no starlink. any help appreciated

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: thanks, i have installed avlinix in order to do some work that had a deadline, however I HATE IT!!!!! i will keep this info for when i install it again, Thank You